# for loop and if statement positioning efficiency

Tags: performance, if-statement, for-loop

I'm doing some simple logic with for loop and if statement, and I was wondering which of the following two positioning is better, or whether there is a significant performance difference between the two.

Case 1:

```
if condition-is-true:
   for loop of length n:
      common code
      do this
else:
   another for loop of length n
      common code
      do that
```

Case 2:

```
for loop of length n:
   common code
   if condition-is-true:
      do this
   else:
      do that
```

Basically, I have a for loop that needs to be executed slightly differently based on a condition, but there is certain stuff that needs to happen in the for loop no matter what. I would prefer the second one because I don't have to repeat the commond code twice, but I'm wondering if case 1 would perform significantly better?

I know in terms of big-O notation it doesn't really matter because the if-else statement is a constant anyway, but I'm wondering realistically on a dataset that is not way too big (maybe n = a few thousands), if the two cases make a difference.

Thank you!

Comment: KISS obviously dictates that 2 is better. Normally because of refactoring.  Compilers probably wouldn't be smart enough to figure out the common stuff on their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one is good one because there is no need to check the condition every time but in second case you have to check the condition on very iteration. But your length of code will be long . If code size matters then put the common code into the method and just call the method instead of block of common code.